# How to properly authenticate against an Instagram Business Account

Tags: reactjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram

I have the following permissions to authenticate against an Instagram Business account so I can get the Facebook pages connected to that account.

```
    export const instagramLogInScopes = [
          "instagram_basic",
          "instagram_content_publish",
          "pages_show_list",
          "publish_video",
    ]

    export async function connectInstagram(cb) {
        window.FB.login(function (response) {
            let { status, authResponse } = response;
            if (!authResponse) {
                console.log("connection failed");
            } else {
                if (status === "connected") {
                    console.log(`Connected Instagram User Business account Data=${JSON.stringify(authResponse, null, 2)}`); //This is always coming back as the default facebook account not the business account
                    let userId = authResponse.userID;
                } else {

                }
            }
        }, {
            scope: instagramLogInScopes.join(","),
            prompt: 'consent',
            return_scopes: true,
        });
    }
```

When the oauth dialog comes up it is not showing me the instagram business accounts, instead it is showing me the logged in facebook account.

How can I make it show me the instagram business accounts instead so I can select and pick the one I want to connect?

I want it to show me a dialog exactly similar to what is shown below
[image]
Thank you.

Comment: Not the login dialog's job, to provide that kind of functionality. You need to implement this yourself, afterwards - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started#4--get-the-user-s-pages

Comment: @CBroe I understand. I know how to get the pages after I've gotten the access token. My question is, is the above step in the right direction to authenticate against an instagram business account? Because the dialog is always showing me the loggedin in facebook account instead of business account

Comment: Yes, of course it does - because that's how it works. Did you not read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/overview#app-users ...? _"Instagram Professional accounts are accessed indirectly through Facebook accounts"_

Comment: @CBroe After the user has accepted the first few permissions I'm supposed to see another dialog that says **Which Instagram Business Account do you want to use with MyAppName** But that dialog is not showing up. That's where I'm confused. My use case is ReactJS

Comment: I want the **Which Instagram Business Account do you want to use with MyAppName?** to show up so the user can select the business account he wants to use with my app

Comment: @CBroe I've updated my question with an image of the dialog I want my users to see

Comment: @CBroe I've updated my question with an image of the dialog I want my users to see